# JMeter Load Test on Spring Data Elasticsearch - Why is Search Request so much faster than Index, Update, Delete?

Tags: elasticsearch, jmeter, spring-webflux, spring-data-elasticsearch

I´m new to JMeter and Spring Data Elasticsearch. I´m doing a JMeter load test on a WebFlux Spring Data Elasticsearch Application. For the test I´m having multiple (50, 100, 200,..., 1000) concurrent users to do CRUD Operations with a ReactiveCrudRepository.
Indexing, updating (which is get and replace document) and deleting documents does take about the same amount of time. But search request are always way faster and constant even with more concurrent users(1000).

The test uses pre- and postprocessors to extract and pass the document id and document data between requests. So first I index a document then search for it then update and finally delete. With random think time (2-8sec) in between requests

**Is this normal behavior, that search requests are so much faster or is there something wrong with my jmeter test plan?**

Example results 400 concurrent users:

[image: Table Data 400 users]

[image: ResponseTimes Percentiles for 400 users]

JMeter TestPlan:

`````
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jmeterTestPlan version="1.2" properties="5.0" jmeter="5.4.1">
  <hashTree>
    <TestPlan guiclass="TestPlanGui" testclass="TestPlan" testname="Test Plan" enabled="true">
      <stringProp name="TestPlan.comments"></stringProp>
      <boolProp name="TestPlan.functional_mode">false</boolProp>
      <boolProp name="TestPlan.tearDown_on_shutdown">true</boolProp>
      <boolProp name="TestPlan.serialize_threadgroups">false</boolProp>
      <elementProp name="TestPlan.user_defined_variables" elementType="Arguments" guiclass="ArgumentsPanel" testclass="Arguments" testname="User Defined Variables" enabled="true">
        <collectionProp name="Arguments.arguments"/>
      </elementProp>
      <stringProp name="TestPlan.user_define_classpath"></stringProp>
    </TestPlan>
    <hashTree>
      <ThreadGroup guiclass="ThreadGroupGui" testclass="ThreadGroup" testname="Thread Group REACTIVE_User_Test" enabled="true">
        <stringProp name="ThreadGroup.on_sample_error">continue</stringProp>
        <elementProp name="ThreadGroup.main_controller" elementType="LoopController" guiclass="LoopControlPanel" testclass="LoopController" testname="Loop Controller" enabled="true">
          <boolProp name="LoopController.continue_forever">false</boolProp>
          <stringProp name="LoopController.loops">10</stringProp>
        </elementProp>
        <stringProp name="ThreadGroup.num_threads">400</stringProp>
        <stringProp name="ThreadGroup.ramp_time">10</stringProp>
        <boolProp name="ThreadGroup.scheduler">false</boolProp>
        <stringProp name="ThreadGroup.duration"></stringProp>
        <stringProp name="ThreadGroup.delay"></stringProp>
        <boolProp name="ThreadGroup.same_user_on_next_iteration">true</boolProp>
      </ThreadGroup>
      <hashTree>
        <HeaderManager guiclass="HeaderPanel" testclass="HeaderManager" testname="HTTP Header Manager" enabled="true">
          <collectionProp name="HeaderManager.headers">
            <elementProp name="" elementType="Header">
              <stringProp name="Header.name">Content-Type</stringProp>
              <stringProp name="Header.value">application/json</stringProp>
            </elementProp>
          </collectionProp>
        </HeaderManager>
        <hashTree/>
        <HTTPSamplerProxy guiclass="HttpTestSampleGui" testclass="HTTPSamplerProxy" testname="REACTIVE_indexGeneratedDocument" enabled="true">
          <elementProp name="HTTPsampler.Arguments" elementType="Arguments" guiclass="HTTPArgumentsPanel" testclass="Arguments" testname="User Defined Variables" enabled="true">
            <collectionProp name="Arguments.arguments"/>
          </elementProp>
          <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.domain">localhost</stringProp>
          <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.port">8080</stringProp>
          <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.protocol"></stringProp>
          <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.contentEncoding"></stringProp>
          <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.path">/api/person/generator/index</stringProp>
          <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.method">POST</stringProp>
          <boolProp name="HTTPSampler.follow_redirects">true</boolProp>
          <boolProp name="HTTPSampler.auto_redirects">false</boolProp>
          <boolProp name="HTTPSampler.use_keepalive">true</boolProp>
          <boolProp name="HTTPSampler.DO_MULTIPART_POST">false</boolProp>
          <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.embedded_url_re"></stringProp>
          <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.connect_timeout"></stringProp>
          <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.response_timeout"></stringProp>
        </HTTPSamplerProxy>
        <hashTree>
          <RegexExtractor guiclass="RegexExtractorGui" testclass="RegexExtractor" testname="Extract Document ID" enabled="true">
            <stringProp name="RegexExtractor.useHeaders">false</stringProp>
            <stringProp name="RegexExtractor.refname">idFromIndexRequest</stringProp>
            <stringProp name="RegexExtractor.regex">&quot;id&quot;:&quot;(.{20})&quot;</stringProp>
            <stringProp name="RegexExtractor.template">$1$</stringProp>
            <stringProp name="RegexExtractor.default"></stringProp>
            <stringProp name="RegexExtractor.match_number">1</stringProp>
          </RegexExtractor>
          <hashTree/>
          <UniformRandomTimer guiclass="UniformRandomTimerGui" testclass="UniformRandomTimer" testname="Uniform Random Timer" enabled="true">
            <stringProp name="ConstantTimer.delay">2000</stringProp>
            <stringProp name="RandomTimer.range">8000</stringProp>
          </UniformRandomTimer>
          <hashTree/>
        </hashTree>
        <HTTPSamplerProxy guiclass="HttpTestSampleGui" testclass="HTTPSamplerProxy" testname="REACTIVE_searchForPersonDocument" enabled="true">
          <boolProp name="HTTPSampler.postBodyRaw">true</boolProp>
          <elementProp name="HTTPsampler.Arguments" elementType="Arguments">
            <collectionProp name="Arguments.arguments">
              <elementProp name="" elementType="HTTPArgument">
                <boolProp name="HTTPArgument.always_encode">false</boolProp>
                <stringProp name="Argument.value">${idFromIndexRequest}</stringProp>
                <stringProp name="Argument.metadata">=</stringProp>
              </elementProp>
            </collectionProp>
          </elementProp>
          <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.domain">localhost</stringProp>
          <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.port">8081</stringProp>
          <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.protocol"></stringProp>
          <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.contentEncoding"></stringProp>
          <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.path">/api/person/search?id=${idFromIndexRequest}</stringProp>
          <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.method">GET</stringProp>
          <boolProp name="HTTPSampler.follow_redirects">true</boolProp>
          <boolProp name="HTTPSampler.auto_redirects">false</boolProp>
          <boolProp name="HTTPSampler.use_keepalive">true</boolProp>
          <boolProp name="HTTPSampler.DO_MULTIPART_POST">false</boolProp>
          <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.embedded_url_re"></stringProp>
          <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.connect_timeout"></stringProp>
          <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.response_timeout"></stringProp>
        </HTTPSamplerProxy>
        <hashTree>
          <RegExUserParameters guiclass="RegExUserParametersGui" testclass="RegExUserParameters" testname="Inject personID to search request" enabled="true">
            <stringProp name="RegExUserParameters.regex_ref_name">idFromIndexRequest</stringProp>
            <stringProp name="RegExUserParameters.param_names_gr_nr">1</stringProp>
            <stringProp name="RegExUserParameters.param_values_gr_nr">2</stringProp>
          </RegExUserParameters>
          <hashTree/>
          <RegexExtractor guiclass="RegexExtractorGui" testclass="RegexExtractor" testname="Extract Response Body" enabled="true">
            <stringProp name="RegexExtractor.useHeaders">false</stringProp>
            <stringProp name="RegexExtractor.refname">JSONdocument</stringProp>
            <stringProp name="RegexExtractor.regex">(?s)(^.*)</stringProp>
            <stringProp name="RegexExtractor.template">$1$</stringProp>
            <stringProp name="RegexExtractor.default"></stringProp>
            <stringProp name="RegexExtractor.match_number">1</stringProp>
          </RegexExtractor>
          <hashTree/>
          <RegexExtractor guiclass="RegexExtractorGui" testclass="RegexExtractor" testname="Extract Document ID" enabled="true">
            <stringProp name="RegexExtractor.useHeaders">false</stringProp>
            <stringProp name="RegexExtractor.refname">idFromSearchRequest</stringProp>
            <stringProp name="RegexExtractor.regex">&quot;id&quot;:&quot;(.{20})&quot;</stringProp>
            <stringProp name="RegexExtractor.template">$1$</stringProp>
            <stringProp name="RegexExtractor.default"></stringProp>
            <stringProp name="RegexExtractor.match_number">1</stringProp>
          </RegexExtractor>
          <hashTree/>
          <UniformRandomTimer guiclass="UniformRandomTimerGui" testclass="UniformRandomTimer" testname="Uniform Random Timer" enabled="true">
            <stringProp name="ConstantTimer.delay">2000</stringProp>
            <stringProp name="RandomTimer.range">8000</stringProp>
          </UniformRandomTimer>
          <hashTree/>
        </hashTree>
        <HTTPSamplerProxy guiclass="HttpTestSampleGui" testclass="HTTPSamplerProxy" testname="REACTIVE_updatePersonDocument" enabled="true">
          <boolProp name="HTTPSampler.postBodyRaw">true</boolProp>
          <elementProp name="HTTPsampler.Arguments" elementType="Arguments">
            <collectionProp name="Arguments.arguments">
              <elementProp name="" elementType="HTTPArgument">
                <boolProp name="HTTPArgument.always_encode">false</boolProp>
                <stringProp name="Argument.value">${JSONdocument}&#xd;
</stringProp>
                <stringProp name="Argument.metadata">=</stringProp>
              </elementProp>
            </collectionProp>
          </elementProp>
          <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.domain">localhost</stringProp>
          <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.port">8080</stringProp>
          <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.protocol"></stringProp>
          <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.contentEncoding"></stringProp>
          <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.path">/api/person/update?id=${idFromSearchRequest}</stringProp>
          <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.method">PUT</stringProp>
          <boolProp name="HTTPSampler.follow_redirects">true</boolProp>
          <boolProp name="HTTPSampler.auto_redirects">false</boolProp>
          <boolProp name="HTTPSampler.use_keepalive">true</boolProp>
          <boolProp name="HTTPSampler.DO_MULTIPART_POST">false</boolProp>
          <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.embedded_url_re"></stringProp>
          <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.connect_timeout"></stringProp>
          <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.response_timeout"></stringProp>
        </HTTPSamplerProxy>
        <hashTree>
          <RegExUserParameters guiclass="RegExUserParametersGui" testclass="RegExUserParameters" testname="Inject personID to update request" enabled="true">
            <stringProp name="RegExUserParameters.regex_ref_name">idFromSearchRequest</stringProp>
            <stringProp name="RegExUserParameters.param_names_gr_nr">1</stringProp>
            <stringProp name="RegExUserParameters.param_values_gr_nr">2</stringProp>
          </RegExUserParameters>
          <hashTree/>
          <RegExUserParameters guiclass="RegExUserParametersGui" testclass="RegExUserParameters" testname="Inject response body to update request" enabled="true">
            <stringProp name="RegExUserParameters.regex_ref_name">JSONdocument</stringProp>
            <stringProp name="RegExUserParameters.param_names_gr_nr">1</stringProp>
            <stringProp name="RegExUserParameters.param_values_gr_nr">2</stringProp>
          </RegExUserParameters>
          <hashTree/>
          <RegexExtractor guiclass="RegexExtractorGui" testclass="RegexExtractor" testname="Extract Document ID" enabled="true">
            <stringProp name="RegexExtractor.useHeaders">false</stringProp>
            <stringProp name="RegexExtractor.refname">idFromUpdateRequest</stringProp>
            <stringProp name="RegexExtractor.regex">&quot;id&quot;:&quot;(.{20})&quot;</stringProp>
            <stringProp name="RegexExtractor.template">$1$</stringProp>
            <stringProp name="RegexExtractor.default"></stringProp>
            <stringProp name="RegexExtractor.match_number">1</stringProp>
          </RegexExtractor>
          <hashTree/>
          <UniformRandomTimer guiclass="UniformRandomTimerGui" testclass="UniformRandomTimer" testname="Uniform Random Timer" enabled="true">
            <stringProp name="ConstantTimer.delay">2000</stringProp>
            <stringProp name="RandomTimer.range">8000</stringProp>
          </UniformRandomTimer>
          <hashTree/>
        </hashTree>
        <HTTPSamplerProxy guiclass="HttpTestSampleGui" testclass="HTTPSamplerProxy" testname="REACTIVE_deletePersonDocument" enabled="true">
          <boolProp name="HTTPSampler.postBodyRaw">true</boolProp>
          <elementProp name="HTTPsampler.Arguments" elementType="Arguments">
            <collectionProp name="Arguments.arguments">
              <elementProp name="" elementType="HTTPArgument">
                <boolProp name="HTTPArgument.always_encode">false</boolProp>
                <stringProp name="Argument.value">${idFromUpdateRequest}</stringProp>
                <stringProp name="Argument.metadata">=</stringProp>
              </elementProp>
            </collectionProp>
          </elementProp>
          <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.domain">localhost</stringProp>
          <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.port">8081</stringProp>
          <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.protocol"></stringProp>
          <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.contentEncoding"></stringProp>
          <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.path">/api/person/delete?id=${idFromUpdateRequest}</stringProp>
          <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.method">DELETE</stringProp>
          <boolProp name="HTTPSampler.follow_redirects">true</boolProp>
          <boolProp name="HTTPSampler.auto_redirects">false</boolProp>
          <boolProp name="HTTPSampler.use_keepalive">true</boolProp>
          <boolProp name="HTTPSampler.DO_MULTIPART_POST">false</boolProp>
          <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.embedded_url_re"></stringProp>
          <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.connect_timeout"></stringProp>
          <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.response_timeout"></stringProp>
        </HTTPSamplerProxy>
        <hashTree>
          <RegExUserParameters guiclass="RegExUserParametersGui" testclass="RegExUserParameters" testname="Inject personID to delete request" enabled="true">
            <stringProp name="RegExUserParameters.regex_ref_name">idFromUpdateRequest</stringProp>
            <stringProp name="RegExUserParameters.param_names_gr_nr">1</stringProp>
            <stringProp name="RegExUserParameters.param_values_gr_nr">2</stringProp>
          </RegExUserParameters>
          <hashTree/>
          <UniformRandomTimer guiclass="UniformRandomTimerGui" testclass="UniformRandomTimer" testname="Uniform Random Timer" enabled="true">
            <stringProp name="ConstantTimer.delay">2000</stringProp>
            <stringProp name="RandomTimer.range">8000</stringProp>
          </UniformRandomTimer>
          <hashTree/>
        </hashTree>
      </hashTree>
    </hashTree>
  </hashTree>
</jmeterTestPlan>````
`````

Comment: Searching normally always is faster on any datastore than insert/update/delete. The latter ones change data which must be replicated across instances for example. It would be strange if it were the other way round.

Comment: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/tune-for-indexing-speed.html - useful read in case you want to tune for better indexing performance

Comment: yeah makes sense, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Search is using [index](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-create-index.html), well behaved index can reduce search complexity from O(n) to O(1), see [Big O notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation) if you're not familiar with the concept. That's why searches are fast and other operations (create, update, delete) are associated with index re-building therefore they're slower.

With regards to your test plan itself:

1. I wouldn't run JMeter at the same machine as the system under test as they may [struggle for resources](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition) and your results will be impacted, if possible use a separate physical machine as the load generator. Also make sure that both have enough headroom to operate in terms of CPU, RAM, Disk, Network IO, etc, if you don't have better choices you can go for [JMeter PerfMon Plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-monitor-your-server-health-performance-during-jmeter-load-test/)
2. JMeter waits for previous sampler to complete before starting the new one, it means that the whole Thread Group will act at the speed of the slowest sampler, it might be a good idea to run these scenarios separately
3. You might also want to replace those Regular Expression Extractors which store the whole response with the [Boundary Extractors](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Boundary_Extractor) with empty boundaries and those which extract IDs - with [JSON](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Extractor) or [JMESPath](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_JMESPath_Extractor) extractors.

Comment: Thanks Dmitri. The test is running on a simple single node cluster with fresh index, so in that case it´s probably O(1) I guess? To 1) Unfortunately I can´t run jmeter on seperate machine, but I´m comparing two applications so it´s the same situation for both and I´m using non-gui mode. PerfMon is showing enough headroom also. 2) The idea was to simulate "real" user behavior by performing these operations in sequence with think time in between if that makes sense? 3) Do the Regular Expression Extractors use to much resources or why would it be better to replace them?